# Qualifying traffic in English

Tags: vocabulary

I am interested in qualifiers for traffic ordered by fluidity. Here is what I would personally use:

- Fluid Traffic
- Heavy traffic
- Congested

However, the last one would qualify the transportation layer rather than the traffic itself. Are there other qualifiers that can be used for the latter, respectively more qualifiers that simply escape the non-native speaker?

Comment: "Congested traffic" does not refer to "the transportation layer" but to the vehicles on the road.  It is a commonplace. But one can also say the road is congested. https://www.google.com/search?q=congested+traffic&oq=congested+traffic&aqs=chrome..69i57.2708j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8

Comment: "[Stop and Go (pulsatile?) traffic](https://m.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1lqdzo/traffic_engineers_what_causes_the_pulsatile_flow/) is often caused when congested roads are at or near their capacity.

Comment: Thank you @TimRomano for pointing that out! I didn't know that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - "traffic" (noun)
> - Vehicles moving on a road or public highway. [Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=traffic+definition&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=yUXLVcqMEayk8wen2bmQCg&gws_rd=ssl)
> - All the vehicles driving along a certain road or in a certain area [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/traffic)

- no traffic
- very light traffic
- light traffic
- moderate traffic
- heavy traffic
- slow traffic
- congested traffic
- traffic jam

Comment: +1, but does 'slow' (or any speed-related terms) really belong in the list ?

Comment: Except in Orange County, which is prone to traffic marmalades. :)

Comment: @tchrist: At night the traffic looks orange on [Spaghetti Junction](http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/West_Midlands_Police_Helicopter_-_Night_Time_Photos_-_Gravelly_Hill_Interchange.jpg&imgrefurl=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravelly_Hill_Interchange&h=1424&w=2144&tbnid=xDxIPMv0WBUe4M:&tbnh=160&tbnw=241&usg=__E7beFeDTKKd3ddRnev0zX7auXGM=&docid=FjGdYSO7JbyMVM&itg=1&hl=en) over here in the UK, but personally I don't think drivers should eat behind the wheel.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer and insights. I would like to point out @PapaPoule 's comment on my question which refers to *Stop and Go* which I think would be synonymous with *slow trafic*.

Comment: also **Queuing traffic**

Comment: Related: Heard a traffic report on the radio in central Florida that went something like: "I-4 is moving very slowly right now - that is to say the _traffic_ on I-4 is moving very slowly".  Good thing he made that distinction, because I was worried the highway itself might be moving...

Comment: Add "parking lot" to the end of that list.

Answer (score 2):

One common idiom for traffic congestion is *bumper-to-bumper traffic*, which suggests traffic is so dense that cars' bumpers are practically touching.